# Children of a UserControl disappear after moving

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls

I've got something like a serious problem.
I made a UserControl which is movable (like a window) in its parent, by using  the `MouseDown, MouseMove,MouseUp` events .
The `[Designer("System.Windows.Forms.Design.ParentControlDesigner, System.Design", typeof(IDesigner))]` Attribute is used that I can add Controls to this UserControl in VS's Designer.

State:

- Moving those UserControls works fine (the Usercontrol moves as expected...)
- Controls can be added in VS's Designer and appear  as designed in Runtime[visible, like it should be]
- throught Moving the UserControl, the Children get invisible, but `.Visible=true` doesn't change
- `.BringToFront();` has no affect (I thought they might be behind the container)

Here's the UserControl class:

```
  [Designer("System.Windows.Forms.Design.ParentControlDesigner, System.Design", typeof(IDesigner))]
    public partial class MovableContainer : UserControl
    {
        bool mdown = false;
        Point mpos;
        [EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Always)]
        [SettingsBindable(true)]
        [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]
        public Axis Rasta { get; set; }
        public static int DefautlRasta = 10;
        public MovableContainer()
        {
            rasta = DefautlRasta;
            InitializeComponent();
            this.MouseDown += ((object o, MouseEventArgs e) =>
            {
                mdown = true;
                mpos = this.PointToClient(MousePosition);
            });
            this.MouseUp += ((object o, MouseEventArgs e) => mdown = false);
            this.MouseMove += MovableContainer_MouseMove;
            this.Paint += (object o, PaintEventArgs e) =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("BTF");
                this.Parent.Controls.OfType<Control>().ToList().ForEach(x => x.BringToFront());
                this.Controls.OfType<Control>().ToList().ForEach(x => x.BringToFront());
                this.Controls.OfType<Control>().ToList().ForEach(x => x.Show());

            };

            this.ParentChanged += ((object o, EventArgs e) =>
                {
                    if (this.Parent == null)
                    {
                        try { this.Parent.SizeChanged -= Parent_SizeChanged; }
                        catch { }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        try { this.Parent.SizeChanged += Parent_SizeChanged; }
                        catch { }
                    }
                }
                );

            // this.KeyDown += ((object o, KeyEventArgs e) => {
            ///kdown = (RastaKey == e.KeyCode); Console.WriteLine("K:"+kdown);
            //});

            //this.KeyUp += ((object o, KeyEventArgs e) => kdown = false);
        }

        void Parent_SizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Boundis = new Rectangle(Parent.Padding.Left, Parent.Padding.Top, Parent.Size.Width - Parent.Padding.Horizontal, Parent.Size.Height - Parent.Padding.Vertical);
            {
                this.Location = this.Location.Add(this.PointToClient(MousePosition).Sub(mpos)).Rasta(Rasta, rasta);
                Rectangle rct = new Rectangle(this.Location, this.Size);
                if (this.Boundis.X > rct.X)
                {
                    this.Location = new Point(this.Boundis.X, this.Location.Y);
                    Console.Write("R");
                }
                //left
                if (this.Boundis.Right < rct.Right)
                {
                    this.Location = new Point(this.Boundis.Right - rct.Width, rct.Y);
                    Console.Write("L");
                }
                //top
                if (this.Boundis.Y > rct.Y)
                {
                    this.Location = new Point(rct.X, this.Boundis.Y);
                    Console.Write("T");
                }
                //bottom
                if (this.Boundis.Bottom < rct.Bottom)
                {
                    this.Location = new Point(rct.X, this.Boundis.Bottom - rct.Height);
                    Console.Write("B");

                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
        }


        void MovableContainer_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (mdown)
            {
                this.Location = this.Location.Add(this.PointToClient(MousePosition).Sub(mpos)).Rasta(Rasta, rasta);
                Rectangle rct = new Rectangle(this.Location, this.Size);
                if (this.Boundis.X > rct.X)
                {
                    this.Location = new Point(this.Boundis.X, this.Location.Y);
                    Console.Write("R");
                }
                //left
                if (this.Boundis.Right < rct.Right)
                {
                    this.Location = new Point(this.Boundis.Right - rct.Width, rct.Y);
                    Console.Write("L");
                }
                //top
                if (this.Boundis.Y > rct.Y)
                {
                    this.Location = new Point(rct.X, this.Boundis.Y);
                    Console.Write("T");
                }
                //bottom
                if (this.Boundis.Bottom < rct.Bottom)
                {
                    this.Location = new Point(rct.X, this.Boundis.Bottom - rct.Height);
                    Console.Write("B");

                }
                Console.WriteLine();

            }

        }
        public Rectangle Boundis { get; set; }

    }
    public enum Axis { X, Y, None }
```

So, how can I fix this?

Comment: could you post the UserControl class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Frankly the code you posted is a big mess - most of the things you put there make no sense. From what I see, you are trying to implement run time movable container with clipping. A simple inherited `Panel` would do the same w/o the need of those designer attributes etc. Anyway, the problem you are describing is caused by the wrong calculations in your `Parent_SizeChanged` handler. Here is a partially cleaned up code that does what I think yours is trying to do w/o having any problems:

```
[Designer("System.Windows.Forms.Design.ParentControlDesigner, System.Design", typeof(IDesigner))]
public partial class MovableContainer : UserControl
{
    bool mdown = false;
    Point mpos;
    int rasta;
    Control parent;

    [EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Always)]
    [SettingsBindable(true)]
    [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]
    public Axis Rasta { get; set; }
    public static int DefautlRasta = 10;
    public MovableContainer()
    {
        rasta = DefautlRasta;
        InitializeComponent();
        this.MouseDown += (sender, e) =>
        {
            mdown = true;
            mpos = e.Location;
        };
        this.MouseUp += (sender, e) =>
        {
            mdown = false;
        };
        this.MouseMove += (sender, e) =>
        {
            if (mdown)
                SetLocation(this.Location.Add(e.Location.Sub(mpos)).Rasta(Rasta, rasta));
        };
        EventHandler onParentSizeChanged = (sender, e) =>
        {
            SetLocation(this.Location);
        };
        this.ParentChanged += (sender, e) =>
        {
            if (parent != null) parent.SizeChanged -= onParentSizeChanged;
            parent = Parent;
            if (parent != null) parent.SizeChanged += onParentSizeChanged;
        };
    }
    private void SetLocation(Point location)
    {
        var rect = new Rectangle(location, Size);
        var clipRect = Parent.DisplayRectangle;
        if (rect.Right > clipRect.Right) rect.X -= (rect.Right - clipRect.Right);
        if (rect.X < clipRect.X) rect.X = clipRect.X;
        if (rect.Bottom > clipRect.Bottom) rect.Y -= (rect.Bottom - clipRect.Bottom);
        if (rect.Y < clipRect.Y) rect.Y = clipRect.Y;
        location = rect.Location;
        if (this.Location == location) return;
        this.Location = location;
    }

}
public enum Axis { X, Y, None }
// You haven't provided these, so I'm guessing by the usage 
static class Utils
{
    public static Point Add(this Point left, Point right)
    {
        return new Point(left.X + right.X, left.Y + right.Y);
    }
    public static Point Sub(this Point left, Point right)
    {
        return new Point(left.X - right.X, left.Y - right.Y);
    }
    public static Point Rasta(this Point pt, Axis axis, int value)
    {
        // Have absolutely no idea what is this about
        return pt;
    }
}
```